# jQuery Mobile, Select All Items in an option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Ok, so I have an issue selecting all items in a multiple select in jQuery Mobile.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u41yk3fy/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="sel">Select the Options</label>
        <select name="sel" id="sel" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Prod 1</option>
            <option value="2">Prod 2</option>
            <option value="3">Prod 3</option>
            <option value="4">Prod 4</option>
            <option value="5">Prod 5</option>
            <option value="6">Prod 6</option>
        </select>
        <div class="floatright" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" id="selectall" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Select All</a>
            <a href="#" id="deselectall" data-role="button" data-icon="minus">Deselect All</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectAll(select) {
    if (select == false) {
        $("#sel option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    } else {
        $("#sel option").attr("selected", "true");
    }

    $("#sel").selectmenu("refresh", true);
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#selectall').click(function (event) {
        return selectAll(true);
    });

    $('#deselectall').click(function (event) {
        return selectAll(false);
    });
});
```

Basically on Chrome, Opera and Safari this actually works. Using IE and Firefox if you select all and deselect all, attempting to select all again no longer works. I have a feeling that this might be a jQuery, jQuery Mobile or Javascript issue and not something I'm doing wrong. However, if I am doing something wrong I'd appreciate the input.

Comment: What is you use $(document).on("pagecreate", "#one", function(){... instead of $(document).ready(function () {... : http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u41yk3fy/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function selectAll(select) {
    if (select == false) {
        $("#sel").val([]);
    } else {
        $("#sel option").prop("selected",  true);
    }

    $("#sel").selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/kpssgkd1/).